# PrimeNG TreeTable Level Styling

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-treetable

I have implemented `TreeTable` from [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/treetable).

Requirement is to add doted lines between levels for usability perspective.

[image]

I have tried multiple approaches but since it is generating HTML structure

```
<table>
  <div>
    <td></td>
  </div>
<table>
```

I don't able figure out proper solution to implement it.

Is it possible to implement with `PrimeNG` `TreeTable`?

Comment: Did you find solution to this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar question. Since I didn't dig anything up from Google, I managed my way to solve it somehow (pretty simple!). I know it's been a long time this question was asked, but like me, others might get here too. And although this is not a direct answer, it could help you figure out other ways to achieve your goal (by using styles).

The example below is a cut from my own code, using `Angular 8` and `PrimeNG 9`.

It's a dynamic `TreeTable` to show only if there is data to show, and where I check both, header and data, for column adjusting and for the color styling that I'm applying with the `getOrderStyle()`. And `getTable()` is here used to return names for the header and fields (it's a cool thing).

Quoting The Mandalorian, this is the way:

```
<p-treeTable *ngIf="!isLoading && dataNode.length" [value]="dataNode" [columns]="getTable()">

  <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngStyle]="checkHeader(col.header)">
         {{ col.header }}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowNode let-rowData="rowData" let-columns="columns">
     <tr>
       <td *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index" [ngClass]="getOrderStyle(rowData)" [ngStyle]="checkField(rowData[col.field])">
         <p-treeTableToggler [rowNode]="rowNode" *ngIf="i == 0"></p-treeTableToggler>
         {{ rowData[col.field] }}
       </td>
     </tr>
   </ng-template>

</p-treeTable>
```

That `p-treeTableToggler` line is to show/hide the nodes. Inside the `getOrderStyle(array)` method you just check the value of param `array` to decide which class to apply to each (whole) table row.

```
  getOrderStyle(array) {
    const col = 'column-name'; // the name of a field column you got from your getTable()
    if (array[col] === 'B') {
      return 'order-buy';
    } else if (array[col] === 'S') {
      return 'order-sell';
    }
  }
```

Ok, ok. Here is an example for the `getTable()`:

```
  getTable() {
    return [
      { field: 'code', header: '' },
      { field: 'qtty', header: '' },
      { field: 'price', header: '️' },
      { field: 'total', header: '' },
      { field: 'time', header: '' }
    ];
  }
```

And lets complete this sample with the CSS I used here:

```
.order-buy {
  color: darkgreen;
  background-color: rgba(200, 255, 200, .8) !important;
}

.order-sell {
  color: darkred;
  background-color: rgba(255, 200, 200, .8) !important;
}
```

Of course, I'm only using `!important` because it didn't work without it for the `background-color`. Some of the styling for PrimeNG tags you need to force your way in.

Good luck (next ones who find this)!